# Django+Celery+postgresql_psycopg2 connection already closed error

Tags: django, postgresql, celery, psycopg2, django-celery

After forcefully killing (kill -9) the idle db connections. Celery log showing the below error

```
[2016-03-08 19:28:04,765: CRITICAL/MainProcess] Task users.tasks.refresh_trend_buzz_messages[85a2430a-9a39-4979-b99d-fcaae86b3ba1] INTERNAL ERROR: InterfaceError('connection already closed',)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/.virtualenvs/backend/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 253, in trace_task
    I, R, state, retval = on_error(task_request, exc, uuid)
  File "/home/.virtualenvs/backend/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 201, in on_error
    R = I.handle_error_state(task, eager=eager)
  File "/home/.virtualenvs/backend/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 85, in handle_error_state
    }[self.state](task, store_errors=store_errors)
  File "/home/.virtualenvs/backend/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 118, in handle_failure
    req.id, exc, einfo.traceback, request=req,
  File "/home/.virtualenvs/backend/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/backends/base.py", line 120, in mark_as_failure
    traceback=traceback, request=request)
  File "/home/.virtualenvs/backend/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/backends/base.py", line 251, in store_result
    request=request, **kwargs)
  File "/home/.virtualenvs/backend/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/djcelery/backends/database.py", line 29, in _store_result
    traceback=traceback, children=self.current_task_children(request),
  File "/home/.virtualenvs/backend/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/djcelery/managers.py", line 42, in _inner
    return fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/.virtualenvs/backend/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/djcelery/managers.py", line 181, in store_result
    'meta': {'children': children}})
  File "/home/.virtualenvs/backend/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/djcelery/managers.py", line 87, in update_or_create
    return get_queryset(self).update_or_create(**kwargs)
  File "/home/.virtualenvs/backend/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/djcelery/managers.py", line 70, in update_or_create
    obj, created = self.get_or_create(**kwargs)
  File "/home/.virtualenvs/backend/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 373, in get_or_create
    return self.get(**lookup), False
  File "/home/.virtualenvs/backend/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 301, in get
    num = len(clone)
  File "/home/.virtualenvs/backend/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 77, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/home/.virtualenvs/backend/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 854, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
  File "/home/.virtualenvs/backend/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 220, in iterator
    for row in compiler.results_iter():
  File "/home/.virtualenvs/backend/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 710, in results_iter
    for rows in self.execute_sql(MULTI):
  File "/home/.virtualenvs/backend/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 780, in execute_sql
    cursor = self.connection.cursor()
  File "/home/.virtualenvs/backend/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 159, in cursor
    cursor = util.CursorWrapper(self._cursor(), self)
  File "/home/.virtualenvs/backend/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 131, in _cursor
    return self.create_cursor()
  File "/home/.virtualenvs/backend/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 99, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/home/.virtualenvs/backend/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 131, in _cursor
    return self.create_cursor()
  File "/home/.virtualenvs/backend/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py", line 139, in create_cursor
    cursor = self.connection.cursor()
InterfaceError: connection already closed
```

I'm using Django==1.6.1, celery==3.1.10, django-celery==3.1.10 and psycopg2==2.4.1

How can I fix the error ?

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected behaviour. Each celery worker will open a connection to the database and try to reuse it to avoid the overhead of negotiation every time. By killing the database processes you close the connection, hence the error.

What are you trying to achieve by killing the database processes?

Comment: Actullaty after some changes in code I can see the postgres keeping idle connections every day and it raise an error "remaining connection slots are reserved for non-replication superuser connections". Thats why I removed the idle process that started before a couple of days..

Comment: How can I fix this ?

Comment: You may need to raise the maximum number of connections PostgreSQL permits

Answer (score 0):

You need to adjust [max_connections](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-connection.html#GUC-MAX-CONNECTIONS) in your PostgreSQL configuration.

You will need at least 1 connection for each celery worker plus enough for any other client code.

Comment: In my case it is not normal to create these 90+ idle connections. My guess is the celery workers is not closing the connections properly. But only change that I made in the last week is a query change (added a sorting to the existing query).
Is there any possibility by celery to keep connections without closing it properly?

Comment: Why is it not normal? Each celery worker opens a connection to the database and keeps it open. This is expected behaviour? How many celery workers do you have? If you have 90 workers then you will have 90 connections.

Comment: I have only 8 workers running. But after killing the old 90+ idle connections and restarting the celery, things are back normal and now only keeping 8 connections.